# Дуплексив или синкретический член предложения

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика

Здравствуйте. Увидела ответ Людмилы. Засомневалась. Разве дуплексив и синкретический член предложения не то же самое?

Comment: А в чём засомневались?

Comment: А что за ответ то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дуплексив-частный случай термина "синкретический член предложения "

http://literary.ru/literary.ru/show_archives.php?subaction=showfull&id=1206018568&archive=1206184486&start_from=&ucat=&

Comment: Вы ведь о предложении: "Поехал к сестре в Александровку", где автор предположил, что здесь возможно уточнение, если "к сестре" принять за обстоятельство? (к сестре=домой). В разговорной речи всё возможно, это так называемое авторское, потому и запятые возможны при определённом понимании  значения слов.

Comment: Да, именно об этом.

Comment: Спасибо! Поняла!